# chat via web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to be able to "chat" between two sessions. I am thinking about using the global class or app class to send messages back and forth between the sessions. Am I on the right track or is there a smoother way to do this? I find almost nothing about communicating between sessions. If I have more than the two sessions, I need to identify the session objects to know who which sessions are talking.

I am relatively new to aspx (I've done 3 fairly complex web apps), use dot net 3.5, VS2008 and C#.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Cache object as that can be read by all sessions.  However, without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, it's hard to tell you which direction to go.